# Como organizar conteúdo JSON

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web

noite!

Preciso da ajuda de vocẽs na seguinte questão:
Tenho 2 arquivos .json, porém ao abrir no notepad++ percebo que o conteúdo esta desorganizado.

Exemplo:

**Arquivo1.json**

```
{
"xxx.yyy.E-mail": "E-mail",
"xxx.yyy.Senha": "Senha",
"xxx.yyy.Voltar": "Volver",
"xxx.yyy.Enviar": "Enviar",
"xxx.yyy.Sair"  : "Sair",
}
```

**Arquivo2.json**

```
{
"xxx.yyy.E-mail": "E-mail",
"xxx.yyy.Voltar": "Volver",
"xxx.yyy.Senha": "Senha",
"xxx.yyy.Sair"  : "Sair",
"xxx.yyy.Enviar": "Enviar",
}
```

Se observarem a ordem está diferente!
Eu preciso ordenar o arquivo2.json pra que fique na mesma ordem do Arquivo1.json, isso tendo em consideração que os arquivos contém mais de 3000 linhas ao abrir no notepadd++.

Existe alguma forma de ordenar o conteúdo do json ?
Eu preciso organizar pra depois comparar os conteúdos linha por linha.
Obrigado desde já!!!

Comment: Se sua aplicação depende da ordem dos dados do JSON ela provavelmente tem um problema de arquitetura (ou nem deveria usar JSON, e sim algum formato "fixo", como texto puro). Sugiro repensar no problema real, que é primeiro interpretar o JSON na sua aplicação, e depois comparar os elementos individualmente.

Comment: Se quiser apenas comparar no editor de texto, selecione os 2 arquivos e ordene alfabeticamente. Depois aplique um diff nos arquivos (mas aí a questão talvez já esteja "quase fora" :P do escopo do site).

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro gostaria de sugerir uma edição do seu Json para que o retorno fique legível, alguém pode mexer no código que um dia não seja você! Então faria algo no sentido:
   Escreva seu arquivo usando Javascript, se não souber como disponibilizo o link
   https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

```
 var Json =    
{
"xxx.yyy.E-mail": "E-mail",
"xxx.yyy.Senha": "Senha",
"xxx.yyy.Voltar": "Volver",
"xxx.yyy.Enviar": "Enviar",
"xxx.yyy.Sair"  : "Sair",
 }
```

Após isso Faria uma função de ordenação muito simples:

```
function OrdenarPorNome()
{
   Json.sort(function (a, b) { return a.Json > b.Json ? 1 : -1; });
}
```

Espero ter ajudado forte abc

Comment: Gabriel Lucchese, muito obrigado por responder e sua preocupação!!! Desculpa minha ignorância mais onde executo isso?
Eu não sou programador javascript, somente recebi os arquivos.
Pode me orientar mais por favor?

Comment: você deve escrever isto dentro de tags <script>//aqui todo o cunteudo como te passei... ou executa o código que o amigo fez aqui em baixo,
 ele já deixou o botão pronto pra vc!</script>

Answer (score 1):

acho que eu não deveria está fazendo isto, mas está ai.

```js
var arquivo_json = document.getElementById("arquivo_json");
var ordenar = document.getElementById("ordenar");
var form = document.getElementById("form");

ordenar.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
  if (form.checkValidity())
  {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function (evt) {
      var json = JSON.parse(evt.target.result);
      var novo = {};
      Object.keys(json).sort().forEach(function (key) {
        novo[key] = json[key];
      })
      var blob = new Blob(
        [JSON.stringify(novo, null, 2)], 
        { type: "application/json" }
      );
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = arquivo_json.files[0].name;
      link.textContent = "download " + link.download + " ordenado";
      document.body.appendChild(link);
    });
    reader.readAsText(arquivo_json.files[0]);
  }
})
```

```css
label {
line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="#">
  <label>
    Arquivo JSON: 
    <input id="arquivo_json" name="arquivo_json" required type="file" />
  </label>
  <input id="ordenar" name="ordenar" type="submit" value="Ordenar" />
</form>
```

Comment: {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
} 

Tobias Mesquita..... selecionei e apareceu isso

Comment: O seu json está mal formado, se estiver utilizando o exemplo que postou, terá de remover a última vírgula.